# Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath' in java for android

Tags: java, android

I am currently dealing with legacy codes in `Java for android`, however this error comes up after I have dealt with the version of the sdk.

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :tcn_liftboard.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > No matching configuration of project :tcn_liftboard was found. The consumer was configured to find an API of a component, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug' but:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
```

Shown below is the Project-Level `build.gradle`

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}


ext {
    compileVersion = 31
    buildVersion = '27.0.3'
    minVersion = 18
    targetVersion = 31
    supportVersion = '27.1.1'
    commonsNetVersion = "3.6"
    glideVersion = "4.8.0"
    traypVersion = "0.12.0"
    gsonVersion = "2.8.5"
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and this is the Module-Level `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tcn.sdk.liftdemo"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.all {
                    outputFileName = "TcnSdkLiftDemo-${defaultConfig.versionName}.apk"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src/main/aidl']
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'   // aar目录
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation(name: 'sdk_auth_lib-release', ext: 'aar')
    implementation(name: 'tcn_liftboard-release', ext: 'aar')
    implementation project(':tcn_liftboard')
}
```

The gradle sync worked perfectly but the error I encounter is during debugging.

I tried changing `buildToolsVersion` to multiple versions, but it does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, i got the answer after discovering it with my colleague. I should delete `implementation project(':tcn_liftboard')` from Module-Level `build.gradle` because it has duplicate issues.